# Root hair formation in Arabidopsis

Tags: botany, gene-expression, plant-anatomy

In arabidopsis, 2 cell types arise in the root epidermis : root hair cells and hairless epidermal cells.

The immature epidermal cells that are in contact with 2 underlying cells of root cortex differentiate into root hair cells whereas the immature epidermal cells having contact with only one cortical cell do not develop root hair.

What is the advantage of this ?